# Confusion with Reactjs syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, babeljs

I'm very new to this, so please bear with me everyone.  I have studied React where a component is created like,

```
var app = React.createClass({ ... });
```

Just like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/).

However, after installing react in my mac, I see that the syntax is a bit different from what I'm used to. i.e.,

```
class Application extends React.Component { ... }
```

Just like [here](https://codepen.io/bradleyboy/pen/OPBpGw/).

Now, I did understand the code due my prior knowledge in Java. But I just wanted to know the difference. This is proving to be a problem for me because when I wrote the syntax like React.createClass(), it didn't work.

If you look at the second [link in codepen](https://codepen.io/bradleyboy/pen/OPBpGw/) you'll see that Babel is written beside JS. So, does react use Babel by default?

I think you get the picture. Thanks!

Comment: First form use ES5 and second form use ES6 syntax.

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer by googling this quickly than waiting for someone to address it here. `React.createClass` also adds a few goodies (e.g. function autobinding) that don't come when you use the ES6 class syntax. This post seems to be a useful read on the subject: https://reactjsnews.com/composing-components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example uses the `React.createClass()` helper function, while the second one uses the [ES6 class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) to define a React component.

Both are valid approaches to defining components. Note however, that you will need to transpile your ES6 code to ES5 before shipping it to make it cross-browser-compatible.

[More info on ES6-style component definitions.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html)